# How to create simple JavaScript error message from form submission?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, bought Jon Duckett's book, but am not a fan of the way he described creating/displaying error messages- Can someone please tell me how to just display an error message if the NAME field is left empty?  Thank you.  Below is the HTML for my form:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Your Details&#58;</legend>
<label for="name">Name&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required"><br>
<label for="email">Email&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
<label for="telephone">Telephone&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone">
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset>
<legend>Your Information&#58;</legend>
<p>
<label for="service">What service are you inquiring about?</label>
<select name="service" id="service">
<option value="Collision">Collision</option>
<option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>
<option value="Custom">Custom</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</p>
<label for="comments">Comments&#58;</label>
<br>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>.    
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the way he described implementing it? How did _you_ implement it? What errors/issues did you run into? If you are "not a fan" as you say, which doesn't mean the author's methodology is wrong, you are asking for others to write the code for you which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this link, this link shows how to do a simple JavaScript form validation

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

**HTML Code**

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="form.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Your Details&#58;</legend>
<label for="name">Name&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
<label for="email">Email&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
<label for="telephone">Telephone&#58;</label><br>
<input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone">
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset>
<legend>Your Information&#58;</legend>
<p>
<label for="service">What service are you inquiring about?</label>
<select name="service" id="service">
<option value="Collision">Collision</option>
<option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>
<option value="Custom">Custom</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</p>
<label for="comments">Comments&#58;</label>
<br>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>.    
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (x === "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Check functionality here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvNGMZ

Comment: Thank you, am looking at the link.  What does this part of the code mean for document.forms?  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;

Comment: That part will get the value that the user entered in the html form into the JavaScript section and store it inside the variable x, so then this variable can be used for validation. "myForm" is the name of the form, this can be specified by setting a name attribute to the form tag. "fname" is the name of the input field in your case it's "name".

Comment: Thank you for the link.  Got it to work after linking the script in the HTML page.  What can I do if I want an error message instead of an alert box?

Comment: You can create an empty div in your html file with the `id="error"` and then,
use
`document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "error message";`
instead of the alert box

Comment: Please mark the answer correct, by checking the tick beside the answer, if you found my answer useful.

Comment: I did add an empty <span> element right after the name section.  Here is the JavaScript, but I feel it is wrong-                                                    function validateForm() 
{
    var name = getElementById["error"]["name"].innerHTML = "error message";
    if (name == "") 
{
    return false;
}
}

Comment: `function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    if (x === "") {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "error message";
        return false;
    }
}`

Comment: Does it have to uploaded into my server so I can test this?  Is this correct?               function validateForm() 
{ 
    var x = document.forms["contactForm"]["name"].value; 
    if (x === "") 
{ 
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "error message"; 
               return false;
} 
}

Comment: Yes this is correct and no it doesn't need to be uploaded to the server since all modern browsers are capable of processing JavaScript. You can just run the HTML file in your browser and the JavaScript functionalities should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new element ( span, div ... ), and write an error into it, and append that element after\before your form field, which ocured that error. As a good way, you may make an object, like  `{fieldName:{errorMessage,validationRule}}` , where is fieldName - is your field name, that you need to validate, and errorMessage - is error, which you showing on error, and the validationRule - is regexp, for example, telling you how to validate that field. Or you just may hardcode all of these params. :)

P.s. There are a lot of ways to validate form, to get errors, and to show them. You may really easy search for it and choose the best for yourself.